# How to optimize this function for large dataset (100k rows & 10 cols) using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

This function runs ok, but for up to 20k rows. What could I change to make it run fast?

```
const SOURCE_FILE_ID = 'ID';

function getData() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE_FILE_ID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSheet.getSheetByName('ativcopiar').getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 9);
  const sourceValues  = sourceRng.getValues();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ativ.');
  var destinationRng = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 9);
  destinationRng.clearContent();

  destinationRng.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Sometimes, it exceeds the time limit.

Appreciate any light!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) When Sheets API is used for your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const SOURCE_FILE_ID = '###';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE_FILE_ID).getSheetByName('ativcopiar');
  const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName('Ativ.');
  var destinationRng = dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow(), 9);
  destinationRng.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(dstSS.getId(), "'ativcopiar'!A1:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).values;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values}, dstSS.getId(), "Ativ.", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: It all seems right, but it's giving me an error, saying that the nº of rows in the range must be at least 1 for ```var destinationRng = dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow(), 9);```

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, how about modifying `var destinationRng = dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow(), 9)` to `var destinationRng = dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() || 1, 9);`? And, by modifying this, please test it again.

Comment: I have actually tested accurately just now. I had marked as right, knowing you ace in your answers. However, for this to work, you'd have to change ```const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(dstSS.getId(), "'ativcopiar'!A1:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).values;``` for ```const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SOURCE_FILE_ID, "'ativcopiar'!A1:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).values;``` Thank you for always helping the community!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.